# Building logic gates

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to build a program that will help to solve a complex logic gate scheme. In order to do so, I tried to build basic logic gates and ran a test on them:

```
def isbit(a):
    if(a==0 | a==1) : return True
    return False
  / # creation Not,Nor,Nand,Or(|),And(&),Xor(^) even tho by using bitwise     operators that exsit in phyton.
def Nor(a,b):
    assert(isbit(a) & isbit(b)) ,"inputs to Nor are not Bit Type" # asserst     is equal to  raise - if - not
    return not(a|b)

def Or(a,b):
    assert(isbit(a) & isbit(b)) ,"inputs to or are not Bit Type" # asserst     is equal to  raise - if - not
    return (a|b)

def Xor(a,b):
    assert(isbit(a) & isbit(b)) ,"inputs to or are not Bit Type" # asserst     is equal to  raise - if - not
    return (a^b)

def And(a,b):
    assert(isbit(a) & isbit(b)) ,"inputs to or are not Bit Type" # asserst     is equal to  raise - if - not
   return (a&b)

def Nand(a,b):
    assert(isbit(a) & isbit(b)) ,"inputs to or are not Bit Type" # asserst is equal to  raise - if - not
   return not(And(a,b))

def Not(a):
   assert(isbit(a)) ,"inputs to or are not Bit Type" # asserst is equal to      raise - if not
    return not(a)


def main():
   pass

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


x=1
y=1
print Xor(Nor(And(x,y),Nand(x,y)),Or(And(x,y),Nand(x,y)))
```

the scripter returns :

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   51      
    Nor <module1>   18      
AssertionError: inputs to Nor are not Bit Type
```

I don't get it why it raises my assertion if I send to the function's inputs only `1`s.

Comment: Why not just `return a == 0 or a == 1`, or `return a in {0, 1}`? You don't have to use bit wise operators for *everything*!

Comment: You should try your functions in isolation to ensure they work, before sticking them all together; it makes testing much easier. For example: `for bit in (0, 1, True, False): print bit, isbit(bit)`. Surprised?

Comment: Why are you writing all these functions anyway, considering they don't do anything the Python built-in operators don't already do? I could maybe see a use for `NAND` and `NOR`, but things like your `Not` function don't really add anything.

Comment: Well, all those functions already exist in the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

Comment: fix the identation in your code

Comment: this is what i fixed .check this if it works for you http://ideone.com/XFGtHM

Comment: @learner if you have an answer, *write an answer*. Don't go sending the OP to off-site resources, and if you're not sure *"if it works for you"* **test it**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not very sure because always the output is 1 for all 4 input cases.. so I pasted link in comment.I modified the code there. Sorry if this was against TOC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

```
if (a == 0 | a == 1):
```

is, due to Python's [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), evaluated as:

```
if a == (0 | a) == 1:
```

*(Python isn't C, you don't always need parentheses after `if`)* which can clearly only be true when `a == 1`. Instead, if you're determined to use bitwise operators everywhere, you should have written:

```
if (a == 0) | (a == 1):
```

To my mind, though, simply:

```
return a in {0, 1}
```

is much neater. You shouldn't have the `return True` on the same line as the `if`, and you can return the Boolean directly.

Comment: I have found this comment the most helpful , thank you.
Also I saw what you did with the for (0,1,true,false) it helped me understand my mistake but I am not sure I understand your solution fully.
Is there a reason for choosing dictionary instead of a list or a tuple?
also when I am doing in something does it iterate over the whole object items?

As for the other questions , I am trying to build a program that will solve a complex design base on logic gate  ,  got a little clue to how to do it (graphs and trees) but need to start from something.

Comment: @maor *"I am not sure I understand your solution fully"* isn't really a question. What exactly do you understand, and what escapes you?

Comment: Also as you already found out I have experience in c++ , not on very high level but I am learning OOP on it.

Comment: @maor that's still **not a question**. Also none of what you've written is object-oriented, so I don't see why that would be a problem.

Comment: I wrote a much longer comment but it only shows a part of it and the edit didn't work and I dont know why, I guess it's because I am trying to get a new line by pressing shift+enter ??.
anyway to make a long comment short I am not sure I fully understand what happen when I write in. does it run over all the items like a for in c or does it use other method. And if there is a specific here  reason for using dictionary and not a list or a tuple?

Comment: @maor you can't put line breaks in comments (if you think you need to, it's too long!) `x in y` calls `y.__contains__(x)`; in this case `y` is a `set` (basically a key-only `dict`), so the lookup is faster than in a `list` or `tuple` (`O(1)` vs `O(n)`) as it's based on hashing (i.e. **doesn't** *"run over all the items"* as it would in the others).